# Python module savReaderWriter causing Segmentation fault

Tags: python, spss

I am using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu. I have a script that writes an SPSS .sav file.
If I use ValueLabels with numbers as keys like this:

`{1: 'yes', 2: 'no'}`

the following line causes a Segmentation fault:

`with savReaderWriter.SavWriter(sav_file_name, varNames, varTypes, valueLabels=value_labels, ioUtf8=True) as writer:`

However, if my keys are strings like this:

`{'1': 'yes', '2': 'no'}`

I do not get the Segmentation fault, and my script runs fine. The problem, of course is that I need the keys to be numbers. How can I fix or work around this.

Thank you in advance.

-RLS

Comment: What does it mean to save a "number" to a file? Won't it just be text once it gets there - why not convert your numbers to strings before writing them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you specify a numerical (`varType == 0`) or a string (`varType > 0`, where varType is the length in bytes of the string value), one the following two C functions of the SPSS I/O library is called:

- `int spssSetVarNValueLabel(int handle, const char * varName, double value, const char * label)`
- `int spssSetVarCValueLabel(int handle, const char * varName, const char * value, const char * label)`

Note that `ctypes.c_double` accepts both floats and ints, so the values of numerical variables do not necessarily have to be specified as floats (doubles), they can also be ints.

It appears that you specified a varType > 1 (indicating a string variable), but a 'value label' value which is an int (suggesting a numerical variable). The fix is to make the two consistent. One way is already stated above, the other way is to set the varType for the variable in question to zero.

That said, it is ugly to get this segfault. I put it on my to-do list to specify the argtype attribute for all the setter functions (see 15.17.1.6 on https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html), so you would get a nice, understandable `ArgumentError` instead of this nasty segfault.

If the problem persists, could you please open an issue at https://bitbucket.org/fomcl/savreaderwriter/issues?status=new&status=open, please with a minimal example.

@ekhumoro: savReaderWriter has not been tested for Python 2.6 or earlier (I would be surprised it if works), so a dict comprehension should be fine.

**UPDATE**:
@ RLS: You are welcome. Thank you too, it inspired me to correct this. As of commit 5c11704 this is now throwing a ctypes.ArgumentError (see https://bitbucket.org/fomcl/savreaderwriter). Here is an example that I might also use to write a unittest for this (the b" prefixes are needed for Python 3):

```
import savReaderWriter as rw, tempfile, os, pprint

savFileName = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "some_file.sav")
varNames = [b"a_string", b"a_numeric"]
varTypes = {b"a_string": 1, b"a_numeric": 0}
records = [[b"x", 1], [b"y", 777], [b"z", 10 ** 6]]

# Incorrect, but now raises ctypes.ArgumentError:
valueLabels = {b"a_numeric": {b"1": b"male", b"2": b"female"},
               b"a_string": {1: b"male", 2: b"female"}}

# Correct
#valueLabels = {b"a_numeric": {1: b"male", 2: b"female"},
#               b"a_string": {b"1": b"male", b"2": b"female"}}

kwargs = dict(savFileName=savFileName, varNames=varNames, 
              varTypes=varTypes, valueLabels=valueLabels)
with rw.SavWriter(**kwargs) as writer:
    writer.writerows(records)

# Check if the valueLabels look all right
with rw.SavHeaderReader(savFileName) as header:
    metadata = header.dataDictionary(True)
    pprint.pprint(metadata.valueLabels)
```

Comment: Albert-Jan: You are correct, I was mixing types in varTypes and valueLables. The reason I was doing that is because I was debugging a different issue related to the data types and I was changing each label's type one-by-one in order to find the issue. This process resulted in the mixed types which led to the segfault. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent - glad I be a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the dict before passing it to `SavWriter`:

```
labels = {str(key): value for key, value in value_labels.items()}
```

or for earlier versions of python:

```
labels = dict((str(key), value) for key, value in value_labels.items())
```

The best long-term solution, though, is to re-factor your code so that the keys don't have to be numbers.

**UPDATE**:

If the dicts are nested, then try this:

```
labels = {str(key): {str(key): value for key, value in value.items()}
          for key, value in value_label.items()}
```

Comment: ekhumoro - I tried this code, but unfortunately I am still getting the segmentation fault. Oddly, the resulting labels dictionary still had numeric keys.

Comment: @RLS. You said in your question that a dict with string keys works. Did you verify that the converted dict has the expected format (i.e. print it and compare with an example that is known to work)?

Comment: Yes, I printed the "new" dict before passing it and the keys aren't strings.

Comment: @RLS. Then you're not passing the right dict... Note that the converted dict is named `labels` in my answer. Are you still passing in `value_labels`?

Comment: Yes, I am printing (and passing) the dictionary named labels.

Comment: I should've pointed out that value_labels is a dict that contains several dictionaries itself. It's those inner dictionary keys that I am referring to.

Comment: Okay, so your updated code does indeed print the keys as strings, but as I stated originally, I need them to be numeric. The reason is that I am setting their types to zero (numeric), and therefore they keys need to be numeric so the types match. When they are both strings, I don't get the segfault, but again, I need them to be numeric.

Comment: @RLS. Please edit your question to show a **real** example of a dict you are attempting to pass. Also, try to make it clear what the types of the various keys and values need to be. You probably also need to show examples of `varNames` and `varTypes`.